# Extracting handwritten information from a pdf copy

Tags: pdf, pdf-scraping

I am working on cataloguing a set of records. Converting the paper records to PDF and then to text is not much of a problem. The main issue that I am facing is associated with hand written entries in forms.

The pdfs are all copies of forms that were hand written. Some areas do not seem like a problem to extract (i.e. a hand written X in a box) but others seem more difficult. Though if others have an efficient means of doing this, please let me know.

Is there a way to convert handwriting to Unicode and then extract it?

Comment: Yes. It's called OCR.

Comment: Depending on the volume, sending them offshore to be rekeyed might be cheaper and more accurate.